# Find the cardinality of $\{\{\{1, 4\}, a, b, \{\{3, 4\}\}, \{\emptyset\}\}\}$?

Tags: proof-explanation, solution-verification

So I processed to solve this: set within a set
$$
\Bigg\{\bigg\{\{1, 4\}, a, b, \big\{\{3, 4\}\big\}, \{\emptyset\}\bigg\}\Bigg\}
$$
by doing the following, finding the cardinality of
$$
\bigg\{\{1, 4\}, a, b, \big\{\{3, 4\}\big\}, \{\emptyset\}\bigg\}
$$
which has 5 elements in the set and then afterwards finding the cardinality of $\{5\}$ which has 1 element. Therefore
$$
\Bigg|\Bigg\{\bigg\{\{1, 4\}, a, b, \big\{\{3, 4\}\big\}, \{\emptyset\}\bigg\}\Bigg\}\Bigg| = 1.
$$
Is it correct or I have made a mistake?

Comment: There is no $\{5\}$ in this question. The set has a single element, which is a set. No need to look deeper.

Answer (score 2):

I have edited your question and used set braces ($\{$ and $\}$) of varying sizes to make it even more obvious that the set you are dealing with is of the form
$$
\{A\}
$$
where $A$ is some mathematical object (in this case a set). So this means your set has $1$ element, hence has cardinality $1$. It doesn't matter what $A$ is at this point. It could be a number, a matrix, a function, a topological space, a set containing 5 elements, a set containing 100 elements, a set containing infinitely elements, or a picture of my grandmother.

I also wanted to say something about your explanation (most of this is repeating other comments). So again, the set you're interested in is of the form $\{A\}$, where
$$
A=
\bigg\{\{1, 4\}, a, b, \big\{\{3, 4\}\big\}, \{\emptyset\}\bigg\}
$$
You said you calculated the cardinality of $A$ and got $5$. This is correct. Then you said you calculated the cardinality of $\{5\}$ and got $1$. This is also correct. Then you concluded that the original set has cardinality $1$. Again, correct. So all of these statements are individually correct, but notice that when you string them together they don't really create a logical argument and some of the statements become superfluous. You could have also said "I calculate the cardinality of $A$ and get $5$, then I calculate the cardinality of $\{\pi^2+e\}$ and get $1$. So my the original set has cardinality $1$." Do you see what I mean? The point is that $A$ having cardinality $5$ has no bearing on the cardinality of $\{A\}$.

Comment: Not counting that there is no set $\{5\}$, but a set of cardinality $5$.

Comment: I don't get it, do I need to state:
Cardinality of A and get 5 then I calculated cardinality of  {{1,4},,,{{3,4}},{∅}} and get 1. Is this due to first cardinality.

Comment: @user1981 No, you do not need to calculate the cardinality of $A$. It has nothing to do with the cardinality of $\{A\}$, which is $1$ regardless of what $A$ is. This is really the point of the question.

Comment: For example, suppose I remove the elements $a$ and $b$ from $A$ and then change $\{1,4\}$ (which is an element of $A$) to $\{1,4,17\}$. Does it change the final answer to the question?

Comment: No it will not changing it.

Comment: Yes, that's right. So this is "evidence" that specific properties of $A$, such as it's cardinality or the specific elements it contains, are irrelevant in computing the cardinality of $\{A\}$.

Comment: I got it. It made sense. Had to rethink the definition of cardinality.

Answer (score 0):

I am no set-theorist, but we can see quite clearly that your set has only $1$ element which is a set itself that has as you said $5$ elements. So yes, $1$ is the answer.

Comment: oh okay, sweet. I was self doubting my work like I did something incorrectly.

Comment: There is no reason however to even count the (five) elements of the inner set

Comment: @user1981: Your inner set might have $35$ elements and the outer set cardinality is still $1$.